# Build a drupal module

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal-7, drupal-modules

first of all thanks for the support.

I am trying to build a facebook module, i need to create an administration interface for the module and a front end for the module to display friends of a user.

I need to select the permissions from the administration panel of the module and then retrieve user's friends.

Can i do it by using any specific module (except drupal for facebook because it doesn't support graph api) and can you please guide me through this?

i just need some suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to build a facebook module, i need to create an administration interface for the module and a front end for the module to display friends of a user.

Then I’d suggest you start with a Drupal tutorial explaining the basics of creating modules!